# Using an existing AdMob app for different app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, admob, google-play-services

I had an app (a game made with Unity) on Google Play with AdMob ads enabled. I wanted to update it but I forgot my keystore password, so I decided to publish a new app with different package name but I didn't create a new app on AdMob. New app is using the same ad units and app ID with the previous one. I assume it will work since I'm using the same app ID and test ads seem working.

I have several questions;

- Should I create a new app on AdMob as well?
- Is it going to work?
- If I publish the app this way, will my AdMob account be suspended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking for a way to update the app even if you have lost your password? By contacting support or by searching on google.
Googling quickly I found this, maybe you need it: https://medium.com/@farukcankaya/recover-your-lost-android-keystore-file-633c853bd11f

However no, you have to create another app on admob, you can search online for official documentations, where they say that the package name of the admob app must have the same name as the package of the play store app. Furthermore you also need to connect the admob app to the app on the playstore correctly. So you have to recreate everything (app id, adunits, etc ...)

On this other thing, however, I'm not sure but I go by memory: I think that having two identical apps is a violation of the rules of the playstore. So if you create another identical one, I think you should take the previous one off the market.

On functioning it will never be as correct as it should be. If you don't connect it (admob-playstore) and if they don't have the same package name it might work badly or not at all.

I think creating another app on admob is the lesser evil.